# Typos in Hayashi Econometrics? How to understand this 2SLS as an IV estimator

Tags: regression, instrumental-variables, generalized-moments

Below are a few passages of Hayashi's Econometrics.

According to the notation there, $X$ the matrix of instruments, $Z$ the matrix of original regressors, and $Y$ vector of dependent variable.

A few sentences seem to be contradictory with the first page. Ex: in the second picture, he says that $z_l$ is the n-vector for the l-th regressor(l-th column of $Z$).

Also, in the third page, how can he do $Px_k=x_k$, where $P=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$? The dimensions do not seem to match. And how can he say that $z_l$ is the kth column of $X$?

Any help would be appreciated

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "standard" confusing point in matrix-notation related to OLS and IV estimation.

We put the regressors in the regressor matrix as *columns*. *But*, in the notation using sums, we need to show the *rows* of the regressor matrix, i.e. to use the model *observation* vectors. So the lower-case symbol $\mathbf z$ is used at times to denote the regressor vector, and at other times to denote the *observation* vector.

In the first image, the $\mathbf z_1'$ etc denote the observation vector (i.e. it includes one realization of each regressor for period $1$ in this case), which is a $1 \times k$ row vector. 
In the second image, the $\mathbf z_i'$ symbol in eq. $(3.8.12)$ again denotes the observation vector. But the symbol $\mathbf z_i$ *denotes also the observation vector* but written as a column. It does *not* refer to the regressor vector, i.e. it is *not* a column of the regressor matrix, just its row again, written as a column. This is the source of confusion.
Because immediately below in the text, the $\mathbf z_{\ell}$ denotes the *regressor* vector (and so it represents a column of the regressor matrix). Hayashi does use different indices to denote the difference, but one has to get used to discerning what is meant when.

So in the third image, $x_k$ is a *column*, *regressor* vector, of dimensions $n \times 1$, and so conformable for right-multiplication by the $k \times n$ matrix $\mathbf X'$ which is the last element in the projection matrix.

But the book does have mistakes. Go to the book's website and download an elaborate pdf with various errors here and there.

Comment: Alecos, Thanks a lot! ;)
This notation is really bad, specially for someone self-studying... Thank God for this forum and you Alecos. ;)